# how to add z-index to next div in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 divs like below. if i click on a button which is inside slide div it should add z-index to next div and remove z-index from current div. same behaviour should be there for previous button. it should remove z-index form current and add to next sibling.

```
      <div class="slide" ><prev></prev><next (click)="showNextSlide($event)" ></next></div>
      <div class="slide" ><prev></prev><next (click)="showNextSlide($event)" ></next></div>
      <div class="slide" ><prev></prev><next (click)="showNextSlide($event)"></next></div>
```

i tried some thing like this

```
event.target.parentNode.nextSibling.style.zIndex="1000"
```

i got below exception

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'zIndex' of undefined
```

this is the function which im calling when click on next button

```
  showNextSlide(event){
    event.target.parentNode.nextSibling.style.zIndex="1000"
  }
```

Comment: With click try to pass `$index` and use it to target that specific. Can you show us the code that you are using in angular for binding click.

Comment: This happens because your last div return `null` for `style`. check it with `if (event.target.parentNode.nextSibling.style)` before setting zIndex for it.

Comment: There is a div, when i print "event.target.parentNode.nextSibling" i dont see style propery there.